# Call Python (classes and functions) from Matlab Simulink

Tags: python, matlab, class, simulink

I am going to make a simulation in Simulink in which my controller is designed in Python, and I need to call this from the Simulink Matlab Function. I succeeded in getting results when I only defined "def" in python code; however when I defined "class" in Python, I could not refer to the class and desired function in Python (from the Matlab function) I have seen most examples of this, but the majority of them call Matlab from Python or Call Python functions(def). I put my simple Simulink here; I would appreciate it if anybody could help me.

Thank you.

[Simulink Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZ8vf.png)

[Interpreted Matlab function]

```
function out = RunPythonn(uu)

    in1=uu(1);
    in2=uu(2);
    coder.extrinsic('Example.py'); 
    controller=py.Example.Controller(in1,10);
    out=controller.test(in1,in2);

 end
```

[Python code]

```
class Controller:

    def __init__(self,x1,time):
        self.time=time
        self.x1=x1

    def test(self,in1,in2):
        out=in1+in2+self.x1
        return out
```

I expect to call each Python classes and functions which I need from Interpreted Matlab function. at each time step, I need to call python code.

Comment: “I could not refer to the class and desired function in Python (from the Matlab function)” Why not? What is wrong with the code you posted? Please copy-paste full error messages into your post.

Comment: Did you try `out = test(controller, in1, in2);`?